# How to cache poetry install for GitHub Actions

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, python-poetry

I tried to use this `actions/cache@v2` to cache poetry venv. There are only two libraries `pylint` and `pytest` installed. It seems that installation was cached (cache size ~ 26MB). However, they couldn't be retrieved after cache hit.

The cache installed libraries are not found while run

> poetry run pip list

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.1.1
setuptools 41.2.0
```

https://github.com/northtree/poetry-github-actions/runs/875926237?check_suite_focus=true#step:9:1

The YAML is [here](https://github.com/northtree/poetry-github-actions/actions/runs/170795796/workflow).

Could I know how to use `actions/cache@v2` to cache poetry installation / virturalenv to avoid reinstalling dependencies.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

@northtree's answer is correct, but for anyone browsing, you should know that the referenced action is no longer maintained.

For Poetry installs using versions >= 1.1.0 I'd recommend using this snippet to cache your Poetry dependencies:

```yaml
...
- name: Install poetry
  uses: snok/install-poetry@v1.0.0
  with:
    virtualenvs-create: true
    virtualenvs-in-project: true
- name: Load cached venv
  id: cached-poetry-dependencies
  uses: actions/cache@v2
  with:
    path: .venv
    key: venv-${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/poetry.lock') }}
- name: Install dependencies
  run: poetry install
  if: steps.cached-poetry-dependencies.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
...
```

More complete examples are documented [here](https://github.com/snok/install-poetry) :)

Comment: Thanks for your work. I have changed to accept your answer, please keep on maintain your GH actions :)

Answer (score 27):

Caching is integrated natively to `actions/setup-python` (https://github.com/actions/setup-python#caching-packages-dependencies):

```yaml
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Install poetry
  run: pipx install poetry
- uses: actions/setup-python@v3
  with:
    python-version: '3.9'
    cache: 'poetry'
- run: poetry install
- run: poetry run pytest
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, as of May 2022

Comment: I was about to answer this!

Comment: FYI: As of today there is a bug even in the latest version 4.5.0 where using `cache: 'poetry'` does not work.

Comment: This is the official way. Also you can specify the poetry version by using `pipx install poetry==VERSION_NAME`

Answer (score 6):

In your YAML file you are using `dschep/install-poetry-action@v1.3` to install Poetry, which sets `poetry config virtualenvs.create false`, which means that the current python interpreter/virtualenv is used. Because you're not activating a virtualenv anywhere poetry is just using the system python and there isn't a virtualenv inside the `~/.poetry` directory.

It should work if you set `poetry config virtualenvs.create true`, e.g.:

```
    - name: Install poetry
      uses: dschep/install-poetry-action@v1.3

    - name: Configure poetry
      run: |
        poetry config virtualenvs.create true
        poetry config virtualenvs.in-project false
        poetry config cache-dir ~/.poetry
        poetry config virtualenvs.path ~/.poetry/venv
```

NOTE: According to the docs for `dschep/install-poetry-action` there is an option to set `poetry config virtualenvs.create true` during install but it seems to be broken at the moment (see https://github.com/dschep/install-poetry-action/issues/11). In any case I personally prefer doing it in the same config block as everything else.

Comment: Just a heads up. The solution provided in these answers is CORRECT. But that Action is no longer maintained. Check @Sondre's answer for an up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use an external action for installing Poetry, or set up virtual environments. `poetry` installs modules to `~/.cache/pypoetry`, so:

```yaml
    - name: Load cached venv
      id: cached-poetry-dependencies
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: |
          ~/.cache/pypoetry
          .venv
        key: poetry-${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/poetry.lock') }}

    - name: Install poetry no matter what
      run: |
        curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
        echo "$HOME/.local/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH

    - name: Install requirements
      if: steps.cached-poetry-dependencies.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      run: |
        poetry install
```

It should theoretically be possible to cache installation of `poetry` too, which is installed to `~/.poetry`. I couldn't find the way, though.

However, by the time you read this, [this PR might have already landed](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/pull/281/files) so all you're going to need to cache Poetry deps is `actions/setup-python`

Comment: Poetry gets installed to `$HOME/.local/bin`, so you could cache that path and have it available on subsequent runs.